# How to preload images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to preload images on my web page. I've seen a lot of discussions about it and most of them suggest to create an *Image* object then edit the *src* attribute. However this doesn't work on the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. The request is marked as "pending" until the image is actually shown on the page and then I can notice a little delay before the image to be shown. Even creating an actual *img* tag on the page (with display:none) doesn't work until the image is shown. And finally when I try the following code, only the last image of the loop is actually loaded

```
var img = document.getElementById('some_visible_image');
for(var i=1;i<5;i++)
    for(var j=1;j<3;j++){
        img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_green.png';
        img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_orange.png';
        img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_red.png';
    }
```

So how can I reduce the loading time of the images (without using large sprites)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create instance for every image

```
// redirect after all the images are preloaded
function redirect() {
  location.href = "yourtargetpage.html";
}

// should solve the first-time-load problem
var loads = 0;
function loaded() {
  // the total number of images needed to load
  if(++loads==42) redirect();
}

// if all the images aren't loaded in 3 seconds, don't wait further
setTimeout(redirect, 3000);

for(var i=1;i<5;i++)
for(var j=1;j<3;j++){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_green.png';
  if(img.complete) loaded(); // if cached, onload isn't fired sometimes
  else img.onload = loaded; // fires for the first time the page loads
}
```

or the `src` is overwritten before the image has a chance to load.

To show your images immediately after the first load, you may run this script on a different page, wait until every image

Comment: Thanks. The images are now loaded on FF (I can see that in Firebug) but I still notice a delay when the image is shown for the first time (after I clean the cache). Is there something to do about it? It works fine on Opera though.

Comment: I can see the problem : the request is actually sent by Firefox when I run the JS code, but then Firefox sends the request again when I want to show the image for the first time. Then it seems like the image is actually cached.

Comment: Thanks, but I found a simpler solution. I answered the question below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, thanks to Jan Turoň's answer. Here is my code :

```
for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
    for(var j=1;j<=3;j++){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_green.png';
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_orange.png';
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_red.png';
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'images/'+i+'_'+j+'_grey.png';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `visibility:hidden;` instead of `display:none;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would be the same as with the code I wrote above, with a visible temporary image.